# Tab Bar Tab width customize | Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Default the Tabar Tab width are equal.
[image]

How i can change each tabbar tab width differently ?

I tried this but not work

```
TabBar(
                    controller: _navController,
                    tabs: [
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 30,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/home.svg",height: height * .02,),
                            onPressed: () {  },
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 40,
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/user.svg",height: height * .02,),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                            ),
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 20,
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/settings.svg",height: height * .02,),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                            ),
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 10,
                          child: Container()),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Expecting Result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have different sizes in tab bar you have to add `isScrollable: true`. Please try this example

```
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyTabbedPage> createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Widget> myTabs = [
    SizedBox(
      width: 20.0,
      child: Tab(text: 'hello'),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 70,
      child: Tab(text: 'world'),
    ),
  ];

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Widget tab) {
          final String label = "Test";
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'This is the $label tab',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```